# Not able to install Oracle Client Library on Mac OS

Tags: oracle, oracleclient

I'm trying to install Oracle Client Library on my Mac. I followed each and every step shown in the doc. But still getting the error as "Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too broad, and off-topic (not about programming in any way)

Comment: Read this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098434/64-bit-oracle-client-library-cannot-be-loaded-in-mac)

Comment: @h.o.m.a.n I'm following the same steps, but still getting error