# Python "DPI-1047 Cannot locate dlopen(libclntsh.dylib)" on macOS

Tags: python, oracle, macos, cx-oracle

I am getting the following error.

`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found"`.

One fix that I found was to insert
`cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=path)` which lead to a Oracle Client Library has already been initialized Error.

However I do not call `init_oracle_client` anywhere in the code. I am using Python 3.8.11 and cx_Oracle 8.2.1 on a Mac.

When I initially ran the code, I did not have any Oracle Client installed. I then downloaded instantclient_19_8, but using that with init_oracle_client lead to the already initialized error.
I saw this here  https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html.

I am not sure where the cx_Oracle binary is, when I go to the location that has my current anaconda environment, I see a cx_Oracle-doc folder that has readme files. In addition, an oradiag_my_username folder has been created in ~.  Not sure what needs to be fixed.

Comment: can you show the code ?

Comment: Is there any connection with the code? Right now the error is at a call of ```cx_Oracle.connect(username,password,dsn)```

Comment: Try the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098434/64-bit-oracle-client-library-cannot-be-loaded-in-mac) and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Probably not as the commentators indicated that it would work for older versions. 
Make sure you are not using the bundled Python. - This seems to be the first instruction. How do you check that.? I can confirm that the version of Python I have is not the same as that in the base environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solution now would be to use the latest cx_Oracle version, which was renamed to python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  This doesn't need Oracle Client libraries (they are optional).

If you use cx_Oracle (or the Thick mode of python-oracledb), you can use something like this:

```
import os
import platform
if platform.system() == "Darwin":
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get("HOME")+"/Downloads/instantclient_19_8")
```

This is the most convenient solution.  If you are getting an 'already initialized' error, then make sure you only call `init_oracle_client()` *once* per Python process if you are using cx_Oracle 8.  If you are using the new version ([renamed to python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)), then you can call `init_oracle_client()` multiple times as long as the arguments are the same.

Alternatively you can find your cx_Oracle binary like:

```
cjones@mac:~$ python
Python 3.9.6 (default, Aug 20 2021, 13:36:17) 
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>> cx_Oracle
<module 'cx_Oracle' from '/Users/cjones/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-39-darwin.so'>
```

and then, in a terminal window, do something like:

```
ln -s $HOME/Downloads/instantclient_19_8/libclntsh.dylib $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

This is for macOS - any Linux users reading this should be aware this solution won't work on Linux.

The `oradiag_xxx` directory is for Oracle "client" traces.  You can delete this at anytime.

Comment: Spent way too much on trying see where else init_oracle_client()  was called. Surprisingly still had the error. The symlinks method worked well. Thanks for the oradiag tip, wasn't sure where that folder mysteriously came up from.